# HTTP/1.1 302 Found redirect loop

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http, header

I'm having a problem with our site, in homepage it is working appropriately but when I visit the inside pages it returns 302 Found and keeps on redirecting, I used the logs in inspector element. In chrome it is working, but in ie11 and firefox it keeps on redirecting.

Here is my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

#
#  Full path to your site
#
# RewriteBase /

#
#  Rules
#

#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?do=$1


ErrorDocument 404 /error
```

you can check this link to see what im talking about. http://mst.com.ph and then try: http://mst.com.ph/category/motoring/

Comment: There is no 302 rule here. Do you have any other .htaccess any where in the system?

Comment: that's the case actually, it is working fine. but suddenly not after some configuration in the server. and yes i have htaccess in min folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After inspecting your page, `/motoring/category` is send with a `302 Moved Temporarily` header. The location is however empty. I am assuming that the php page you are trying to load has a `header( ... )` in it, and that the variable that contains the new location is empty or NULL. Besides that, the request is not terminated with an `exit()`, so the content is shown anyway. Chrome decides to ignore the status code and display whatever you sent as content after it, and other browsers apparently decide to redirect to the same page. In any case, it doesn't make sense to serve the page with a 302 status code.

This is not a problem with your .htaccess. In your script, make sure that variables contain what you believe they should contain. (`var_dump(..)` them for example). Also add an `exit()` behind headers that define a redirect.